# How can I specify the right document path in cloud functions index.js file?

Tags: node.js, swift, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So, I've been skimming through stack overflow questions regarding a Firestore document time-to-live and wanted to implement that exact feature within my iOS app. I seen a reoccurring link to a blog by this Doug Stevenson guy showing how to do exactly that and followed the steps up to the point where he declares the first function, now the issue with my document path is that it is dynamic and all those variables and values are in my Swift files in Xcode.

I have this block of code in my `functions/index.js` file in VSC, but I'm getting a headache trying to wrap my head around how I can connect all these things together to make it work.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin =  require("firebase-admin")
const { CloudTasksClient } = require("@google-cloud/tasks")
admin.initializeApp()

export const OnCreateGothereEvent = functions.firestore.document('school_users/[school_userDocID goes here]/events/[eventDocID goes here]').onCreate()
```

I don't know how to go about doing this, it was already confusing enough trying to get to this point but some extra guidance would be greatly appreciated. I've seen documentation of where Cloud Functions was being used in Swift a bit, but I know to setup the actual task/function, you need to use Node.js, so I need some guidance with that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture those values (ie `school_userDocID` and `eventDocID`) by using the `{}` syntax in your function definition.

```
export const OnCreateGothereEvent = functions.firestore
  .document("/school_users/{schoolID}/events/{eventID}")
  .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
    const schoolID = context.params.schoolID;
    const eventID = context.params.eventID;
```

Comment: the fields were just examples in my question, when implementing the code you just sent me, should I use the exact name of the fields of the firestore document? @jnpdx

Comment: What is inside the `{ }` doesn't have to be exact -- think of it like a variable assignment. It's just going to capture whatever is in that part of the path. The only important part is that what you name inside { } has to match what you say after `.params`. Note mine (schoolID -> schoolID) and (eventID -> eventID)

Comment: Noted. Thanks, i'll accept the answer when everything works. @jnpdx

Comment: Lol. funny story. I ended up ditching it and using a function I created in Swift to delete expired docs by matching a certain field with the current date, it kinda sorta works because the timing is inaccurate but I know once i get it fixed, it'll be perfectly fine. I asked a question about it, but nobody responded. @jnpdx